# piece of jquery code not working in internet explorer

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a piece of code below where it displays 2 drop down menus, one for buildings and other for rooms. When the user selects a building from its drop down menu, it will use the ajax to navigate to room.php where in that script it compiles a query and outputs a list of rooms which is then displayed in the rooms drop down menu back on this page:

```
         $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Building FROM Room"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbBuilding);

 $buildings = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

 $buildingHTML = "";  
 $buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingsDrop" onchange="getRooms();">'.PHP_EOL; 
 $buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
 { 
     $building = $dbBuilding; 
     $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
  } 

  $buildingHTML .= '</select>'; 

  $roomHTML = "";  
  $roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
  $roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
  $roomHTML .= '</select>'; 


        ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function getRooms() { 
    var building = jQuery("#buildingsDrop").val(); 
    jQuery('#roomsDrop').empty(); 
    jQuery('#roomsDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
          type: "post", 
          url:  "room.php", 
          data: { building:building }, 
          success: function(response){ 
              jQuery('#roomsDrop').append(response); 
          } 
        }); 


 }

 </script>
```

Now the code above works in all browsers except for internet explorer. Thanks to some great advice on SO I have been told to validate the script as internet explorer are really strict when it comes to validation of code.

Anyway in my validation I realize I have this error:

> document type does not allow element "option" here :

Pointing to this line below:

```
jQuery('#roomsDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>');
```

It states it needs to go in a `<select>` tag which I am technically trying to do in the code above. MY question is how can the code be fixed to pass the validation but to be able to perform what it does which is display a list of rooms in rooms drop down menu after a building is selected from building drop down menu?

Below is the application, please open the application in internet explorer and also in either chrome, firefox, opera or safrai. Text the app first in one of the non internet explorer browsers to see how the app works and then test it in internet explorer and you can see the problem for yourself and what I am trying to achieve.

[Application (Please open in Internet Explorer and in one other major browser)](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text11.php)

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Room </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roomStyle.css">
</head>



<body>

<?php

     // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}


$building = isset($_POST['building']) ? $_POST['building'] : ''; 

$sql = "SELECT Room FROM Room WHERE Building = ?"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$building);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbRoom);


$roomHTML  = "";  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
    $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$dbRoom."'>" . $dbRoom . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
} 


echo $roomHTML; 

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define doesn't work in IE?

Comment: Besides telling us how it fails, please show the html and the body of the ajax response.

Comment: check the actual response data received in browser console...is there any garbage being added to it somehow? Does problem occur in all versions of IE? Does IE throw any script errors? Also try alerting the data in success callback to see if it is firing...if not add some ajax error handling and find out what specific ajax error is

Comment: validate your whole page.... as per your other post about layout problem, you have invalid html in page so IE is having problems inserting data. Tab is 'Network` for tools. Use W3C validator any time you get problems like this

Comment: In the request it does recognise the URL of room.php when selecting a building. I will try the validation in W3Schools

Comment: @charlietfl Ok in the validation I am getting this error stating "option" not allowed in this line of code here; ` jQuery('#roomsDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); `

Comment: ok...  disregard javascript html parsing. Try removing script while you validate just the html. Can also wrap your JS code in `CDATA` comment and validator will ignore it

Comment: @charlietfl I copied the code from the view apge source and it still states same error `document type does not allow element "option" here` and displaying it in this line  
    `jQuery('#roomsDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>');` If I remove the javascript from the `<script>` tag then the HTML passes validation

Comment: @charlietfl Got ny ideas on how I should manipulate the code? it says the error would be removed if it is in a select tag but if i include the `<select>` tag then it messes it up. Is there a way to include a select tag without it messing the drop down menu up? Or can I do something else to fix it without including a `<select>` tags around the option tag?

Comment: don't understand what issue is other than option tags must be in a select which is a W3C standard

Comment: Put your Javascript in an external file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `room.php` is returning this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Room </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roomStyle.css">
</head>



<body>

<option value='CW2/08'>CW2/08</option>
<option value='CW4/09'>CW4/09</option>
<option value='CW4/10'>CW4/10</option>
<option value='CW5/10'>CW5/10</option>
</body>
</html>
```

when it should only be returning this (based on how you're using the response):

```
<option value='CW2/08'>CW2/08</option>
<option value='CW4/09'>CW4/09</option>
<option value='CW4/10'>CW4/10</option>
<option value='CW5/10'>CW5/10</option>
```

Although I am loathe to say it, Internet Explorer is correct (in this case). `<option>` elements should not be a direct child of the `<body>` element.

The reason this is working in Chrome (for instance) is that Chrome only appends this to the `select#roomDrop`:

```
<title>Room </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roomStyle.css">
<option value="CW2/08">CW2/08</option>
<option value="CW4/09">CW4/09</option>
<option value="CW4/10">CW4/10</option>
<option value="CW5/10">CW5/10</option>
```

and Chrome does not visually render the `<title>`, `<meta>`, or `<link>` elements in the `<select>` element.

There are at least a couple of ways to correct this.

1. Change `room.php` to only output the `<option>` elements.
2. Change your `getRooms()` function to only append the returned `<option>` elements.

As for which of the two fixes above to follow, it would depend on what else you are using `room.php` for. There are other solutions to this as well (I am sure), but ultimately those will boil down to fixing the PHP or fixing the AJAX call.

Without seeing the PHP source for `room.php`, I cannot help with the first. The second can be done like so:

```
function getRooms() {
    'use strict';
    var building = jQuery("#buildingsDrop").val(),
        //use jQuery (or plain JavaScript) to build the option as a DOM element
        defaultOption = $('<option />').text('Please Select').val('');
    //append the DOM element, not an HTML string
    jQuery('#roomsDrop').empty().append(defaultOption);
    jQuery.ajax({
        "type": "post",
        "url": "room.php",
        "data": {
            "building": building
        },
        "success": function (response) {
            //filter out the option elements
            var opts = $(response).filter('option');
            //and append only those
            jQuery('#roomsDrop').append(opts);
        },
        "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //always good to have an error handler.
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

You may notice that I used jQuery to build the initial option as a DOM element, instead of building an HTML string. I did so because:

1. It's generally considered a better practice.
2. It eliminates the need to build an element through string concatenation.
3. It saves me from having to write well-formed HTML (which on long strings can be tough).
4. It doesn't take a lot of effort to do.

**UPDATE:**

As you've included the PHP source for `room.php`, you can modify it to only output the `<option>` elements like so:

```
<?php
    // connect to the database
    include('connect.php');
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        die();
    }
    $building = isset($_POST['building']) ? $_POST['building'] : '';

    $sql = "SELECT Room FROM Room WHERE Building = ?";
    $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$building);
    $sqlstmt->execute();
    $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbRoom);

    $roomHTML  = "";

    while($sqlstmt->fetch()) {
        $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$dbRoom."'>" . $dbRoom . "</option>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $roomHTML;
    $sqlstmt->execute();
?>
```

which is to say, simply eliminate everything that's not related to the `<option>` elements.

Comment: So will I need to remove all of the code above and below the option tags in the room.php?

Comment: Hi, I marked your answer thanks to your Jquery/DOM method. For other people can you include how you would change the room.php to only output options for other people who will see this question. I have included the room.php in the question update

Comment: @user1881090: Updated answer to reflect new PHP source.